# How bad is this gear Box Oil Leak?

Tags: transmission, rebuild

[image: Transmission oil leak.]

How bad is this gearbox oil leak? This is a newly rebuilt Isuzu giga truck and it is odd to have issues like this. My mechanic told me it is not an urgent maintenance.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! From the picture alone, it appears the leak is occurring from what appears to be a power take off (PTO) at the inflow pipe. It could just be the fitting there is leaking. Usually a small leak like this (small leak which has been leaking for a while) isn't a big deal. You just need to keep up on the fluid levels until you can get it fixed.

Comment: Is that really a gearbox?  Look more like a power steering box to me.

Comment: I agree Handy Howie. What ever it is, it has hydraulic lies to it, indicating that it is a pump. If this is the case I would fix the leak because it can cause air to enter the system and it can get worse in short order.

Comment: Easy enough to try to tighten the apparently leaking flare nut.